# Import and display .usdz file in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I try to import some .usdz files into the app and display the 3D model using SceneView. When I display some model which already in my Xcode folder, it works. But when run the app on my phone and try to import files from my Phone, print(fileName) still can get the right file name but nothing displayed in the SceneView... Anyone can help?

```
@State var fileName = ""
@State var openFile = false
@State var model = Model(id: 0, modelName: "")

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        VStack {
            Text(fileName)
                .fontWeight(.bold)

            Button {
                openFile.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Come On")
            }
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.usdz]) {  result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):

                _ = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                print(url)
                self.fileName = url.lastPathComponent
                print(fileName)
                model.modelName = fileName

            case.failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        SceneView(scene: SCNScene(named: model.modelName) , options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl])
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

change `SCNScene(named: model.modelName)` to  `let scene = try? SCNScene(url: url!)`

Example

```
struct Viewer3D: View {

@State var urlLocalModel: URL?
@State var openFile = false

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        VStack {
            Button {
                openFile.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Open File Local USDZ")
            }
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.usdz]) {  result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                _ = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                self.urlLocalModel = url
                print(url)
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        if (urlLocalModel != nil) {
            let scene = try? SCNScene(url: urlLocalModel!)
            SceneView(scene: scene, options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl])
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        }
    }
}}
```